# how to display number without comma java

Tags: java

```
Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
String i = "11,111";


System.out.print("Enter first number a:");
String b = a.next();
```

I want to display number without comma when user provide

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `String::replace`

`System.out.println (i.replace (",", ""));`

Comment: @moh333moh You are welcome.  Please consider to upvote and/or accept this answer

Answer (score 0):

Replace All will do the trick..

```
String i = "11,000";    
System.out.println (i.replaceAll(",", ""));
```

Comment: why use `replaceAll` ?